# why is if(x) not the same as if(window.x)?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

Why this:

```
if(x)
  alert('Available');
```

gives: `ReferenceError: x is not defined`

while this works:

```
if(window.x)
   alert('Available');
```

Isn't saying:

```
var x = "";
```

equivalent to:

```
x = "";
```

equivalent to:

```
window.x = "";
```

as long as **outside** a function, as the whole code is surrounded with a `with(window)`?

To make it clearer: I do know the difference between global vs member variables, but I want to know why retrieving an undeclared variable gives a ReferenceError like `x;` while `window.x` gives undefined? Shouldn't they both give undefined?

Comment: `var` is different inside and outside a function and accessing a *property* will never throw a ReferenceError, only attempting to use an *bare identifier* not in scope (or not defined on the [global] object)

Comment: Neither will alert anything, but undefined property access doesn't throw a reference error.

Comment: `var` outside a function is considered a global variable as it is assigned to `window`.

Comment: Please note from the [ES5 spec §11.13.1 Simple Assignment](http://es5.github.io/#x11.13.1) `When an assignment occurs within strict mode code, its LeftHandSide must not evaluate to an unresolvable reference. If it does a ReferenceError exception is thrown upon assignment.` i.e. `x = "";` when `x` hasn't been initialised is illegal in strict mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason `window.x` "works" (but it shouldn't satisfy the `if` condition) is because when accessing a nonexistant property of an object, undefined is returned, and not an exception. The opposite is true for directly accessing variables. This is most likely because if a variable is accessed before it is defined, chances are the program has a bug that shouldn't be left unnoticed.

Also, `var` defines a variable that can only be accessed in the enclosing scope. Omission of the keyword results in the creation of a global variable.

Comment: That makes sense. (typeof anythingNotIn_window === "undefined"). While (!!anythingNotIn_window) is a reference error, and (!!window.anythingNotIn_window) gives false. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @user3439065 I prefer using `if ("foo" in bar) {/* exists */}` if you can't assume truthy .. and don't mind inheritance

Answer (score 0):

The `x` can be three different things, it can be a global variable, a local variable, or a property in the `window` object.

If `var x = "";` is used outside of any function, it will be a global variable. If `x = "";` is used anywhere that `x` is not already defined, it will be a global variable.

If `var x = "";` is used inside a function, it will be a local variable.

Using `window.x = "";` will create a property in the `window` object.

Getting the value of a variable that is not defined is an error. Getting the value of a property that is not defined is not an error, and returns the value `undefined`.

Comment: What is the difference between a "global variable" and a "property in the window [global] object"?

Comment: Thank you. My question was mentioning outside a function, in which `var x = "";`, is the same as `x = "";`. But wouldn't the 2 previous statements create the variables in the `window` object anyways?

Comment: @user2864740: The difference is only in how you create it. A global variable is available as a property of the `window` object and vice versa.

Comment: @user3439065: Sorry, I missed the part about outside the window, and anyway I wanted to cover any possible use of a variable. Yes, the variables become properties in the `window` object.